# Find Algorithm, Given a List of Arcs, which Maximizes the Number that Fit on a Circle

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find an optimal algorithm that, given a list of arcs $(x_i, y_i)$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the starting and ending angle measurements of the arc in radians, maximizes the number of arcs that can be fit onto a circle.

I'm also curious as to how one might solve the problem of maximizing profit if each arc also had an associated price.

A dynamic programming approach seems relevant, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: What are the constraints?  Do you want the arcs to be non-overlapping?

Comment: Yes, arcs are non-overlapping (it's fine if the overlap on one point, aka $(a,b)$ $(b,c)$ is fine.) Also, all arcs are in [0,2pi), so the problem is really identical to maximizing line segments on [0,2pi)

Comment: ... except you need to check for arcs that contain $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the arcs crosses from fourth to first quadrant, we are reduced to the problem of maximizing line segments in $[0,2\pi]$, or more generally $[L,R]$.
 Here's a DP approach for that:

Sort segments in ascending order according to their right end, i.e., we have segements $[a_1,b_1],\ldots ,[a_n,b_n]$ with $L\le a_1\le b_1\le \ldots\le b_n\le R$. Let $c(k)$ be the profit obtained by using segment $k$ (or $1$ in the basic problem variant). For convenience, let $b_0=L$.
Let $g(k)=\max\{\,j\mid b_j\le a_k\,\}$.

We want to compute $f(k)$, the optimal value optainable from picking segments only $\subseteq [L,b_k]$. Clearly $f(0)=0$ and otherwise 
$$f(k)=\max\{f(k-1),\max\{\,f(g(j))+c(j)\mid b_j=b_k\,\}  $$
The final result is $f(n)$, of course.

Complexity: Sorting takes $O(n\log n)$ time. Computing $g()$ takes $O(n\log n)$ time and $O(n)$ memory. The final DP takes $O(n)$ meory and time.

Comment: If every possible angle is crossed by some arc, pick an angle that is crossed by $k$ arcs, and condition on the segment to be used, if any, that crosses this arc.  It multiplies the complexity by a factor $k+1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes. I left that part out because I understood the OPs *comment* that the restriction I mention in the first paragraph applies

Comment: Is this problem then analogous to the problem of scheduling weighted intervals?

Comment: @GeorgeWatson Yes, that is precisely what we do here

Answer (score 0):

For a simple implementation, I would suggest a variation on the increasing first fit algorithm (this is a fairly standard packing algorithm).

Rank each arc in order of size starting from the smallest to the largest. Size $= y_i-x_i$. The rationale here is that to fit as many as possible, you want the arcs to be as small as possible. If there is an associated profit then rank them by increasing value of $\frac{size}{profit}$.

Starting with the smallest arc (or the smallest $\frac{size}{profit}$ arc), add the arc to your circle. Only allow additional arcs if they do not overlap existing arcs.

Repeat until there are no more allowable arcs.

Comment: This is certainly not optimal

Comment: Not guaranteed to be optimal, but simple to implement. Many packing algorithms are not optimal, but achieve a near-optimal solution with small times.